# CSS min-height isn't working

Tags: html, css

I have an dropdown menu, for an webshop.
But whenever i add more items then there should be, the box isn't getting larger,
Simple question huh? the answer is "min-height". But here's the problem! It isnt working. I've been using it for a long time now, and this is the first time it doesn't work. Are there any specific things i need to know?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I actually didn't know that and thanks for pointing it out. I will go look over the discussion :)

Comment: min-height only applies block elements. What type is your menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 43 in your CSS, you need to set the `height` to `auto`, which is being inherited from line 16, as part of the menu's class declaration.

[Here is the full working coded-up example that I've just done for you.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/)